Early 90s or late 80s movie with monsters in an underground base.
Most of the movie takes part in an underground base. There are monsters or some kind of creatures killing people. One scene takes place in a store room of some kind. At the end a man and a woman escape together through a hatch in the roof. They lift themselves up and are in a small shed. They exit the shed and are in what looks like a desert, they then hide behind rocks and look down at the shed. Two of the monsters (they were either rubber suit or stop motion) come out of the shed and look around it, and then the shed explodes. I think they planted a bomb before escaping or something like that. 

The Terror Within
You can watch the complete movie on Youtube here:



At the end of the movie you can see the scene you describe in your question. Man and woman are the only survivors, they escape to the surface, two monsters follow them to the surface, the monsters approach the shed, guy pushes the button on the remote in his hand and the shed with the monsters explodes.
Two monsters approach the shed:

Shed explodes:


Damn, people on this site are good...lol. That's it, I was starting to think I'd imagined it.

Great. Please mark my answer as the correct answer, there is an option for that. Thank you.
